# Compiling a cross-compiler to compile a kernel, using MinGW

Tags: c, compilation, operating-system, kernel, cross-compiling

I'm looking for a way to compile a hobbyist-written kernel and micro-OS on Windows, so far I've found mostly the advice of "build a cross-compiler" on all the forums and other such places. Unfortunately I lack the knowledge to do it right now, so could anyone please inform me as to how I can compile GCC/Binutils to run on a 64-bit Windows 7 installation using MinGW?  Thanks for your time, Erkling.

Comment: Have you cross-compiled the compiler with the cross-compilation of the compiled kernel with the compiler?

Comment: MingGW already runs on 64bit windows. You don't need a cross-compiler to build a kernel for the CPU arch you're running on. So I'm not sure your question makes any sense.

Comment: The thing is, I've heard that MinGW tends to give "PE operation on non-PE file" (or something like that) when you try to link to the binary output format, which is why I'd like to use a "cross-compiler" of sorts. (I think I got terminology wrong there..?)

Comment: If you are attempting to compile an OS kernel you will require a cross compiler as things such as the binary format will differ and you most likely won't want to include c headers for the compiler either (or you will want to use the headers from the OS you are targeting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling gcc as a cross compiler should be fairly simple, however I have never attempted it on Windows.

To be built as a cross compiler gcc needs to be configured with `--host=<host_os>` and `--target=<target_os` where `<host_os>` is the platform the compiler will run on (windows in your case) and `<target_os>` is the platform you are targetting. As you say it is a hobbyist os it is probably `1586-elf` or similar.

http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler has more in-depth information. Give that page a go and see if it helps. Getting this method working on Windows should be as simple as installing Cygwin with GCC and downloading and building binutils and gcc.

**EDIT**

This was solved by using `objcopy` to strip a PE file compiled with `--nostdlib`. If all you want is a flat binary file then this may be an option for you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the link. I've come across a very obvious answer to my question though, compiling the kernel to PE format and then stripping it with objcopy. Thanks anyway! :) EDIT: Oh, forgot to add this, but I also passed -nostdlib to it. Just incase anyone else comes across this problem as well. :)

Comment: Ok. I wasn't quite sure from your question what you wanted to do that's all. Updated my answer to add what you found. If you could mark it as the solution to the problem then others can benefit.

Comment: Thank you, ticked as an answer. :)